# Como o "printf()" funciona?

Tags: c, c++, printf

Como funciona o código por traz da função `printf()` do C? Tenho noção do que esta função faz, quero saber como ela faz.

Comment: Boa pergunta. Veja essa resposta: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4867229/code-for-printf-function-in-c

Comment: Esta em Inglês, mas da uma boa explicação da função:
[http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/printf/](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/printf/)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Cada compilador pode usar o código que bem entender na sua biblioteca desde que faça tudo o que está especificado. E a maioria disponibiliza o código fonte, então a melhor coisa é olhar lá. Alguns lugares:

- Se tiver o Visual Studio, pode ver no seu computador:

  ```
    C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\crt\src
  ```
- [GCC](http://www.gnu.org/software/libc/)
- [Apple](http://www.opensource.apple.com/source/shell_cmds/shell_cmds-170/printf/printf.c) (especificamente a função que você quer)
- [OpenBSD](http://cvsweb.openbsd.org/cgi-bin/cvsweb/src/lib/libc/stdio/) (todo o stdio)
- [uCLibC](http://git.uclibc.org/uClibc/tree/)
- [Código um pouco mais simples](http://www.menie.org/georges/embedded/printf-stdarg.html)

Note que os códigos costumam ser ruins de ler já que eles procuram ser otimizados e não legíveis.

A função essencialmente faz um *parse* na *string* enviada, imprime os caracteres normais e desvia para funções específicas quando tem que substituir um padrão por um valor que muitas vezes terá que ser convertido para *string* primeiro. Para a impressão depende do sistema operacional ou até mesmo do hardware onde está rodando. Pode ser que precise escrever em uma porta ou pode ter que chamar uma função do SO, ou ainda pode precisar de uma solução mais complexa e específica.

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/C/Conceptual.md).