# Diferença de cout para printf() em C++

Tags: c++, console, printf, cout

Queria saber qual diferença de eu usar no C++ `cout` e `printf()`, é tudo a mesma coisa?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Não, são completamente diferentes, apesar de terem propósitos mais ou menos parecidos.

[`cout`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/cout) trabalha com *streams* de dados. Esses *streams* podem ser personalizados para cada tipo de dado.

A função [`printf()`](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/113302/101) é uma função normal muito simples originalmente criada para a linguagem C e que foi mantida por questões de compatibilidade e porque em alguns casos pode ser mais adequado que `cout`.

Geralmente o `cout` não só é mais adequado e simples de usar em C++, mas também costuma ter melhor performance. Tem uma [pergunta sobre as contrapartes de entrada](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/126240/101).

[Veja mais sobre o `cout` aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/113302/101).

E como funciona a [`printf()`](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/78189/101).

Recentemente consideraram o *stream* algo ruim para grande parte dos cenários semelhantes ao `printf()` estão criando uma solução de formatação para uso opcional.

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CPP/Conceptual.md).

Answer (score -3):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <iostream>
int main(){
    printf("Eu posso misturar printf com cout?");
    cout<<"Em?";
    return 0;
}
```