# Posso substituir o cout e printf?

Tags: c++, printf, cout

Qual a diferença entre `cout` e `printf`?

Eu aprendi usando o `printf` e o `scanf`, mas em um curso online eu vejo o professor utilizando `cout` e algumas páginas também usam `cout`, porém outras usam `printf`...

Posso substituir o `cout` pelo bom e velho `printf`?

Comment: Pergunta duplicada. O titulo não reflete o conteúdo. Podes mudar?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

De forma geral, deve. `cout` é C++, `printf()` é C. [Eles são completamente diferentes, mas o objetivo é o mesmo](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/204071/101).

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CPP/Conceptual.md).

Comment: Aaahh, mas C++ e C são apenas uma lingaguem mais completa que a outra, né?

Comment: Não exatamente, uma empresou algumas coisas da outra, só isso.

Comment: Ata vlw manin tmj

Answer (score 0):

cout é pertence a C++ e está no cabeçalho iostream

exemplo:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    std::string nome; //String que guardará o valor de nome

    //cin equivale á scanf() em C++
    std::cin >> nome; //Pega o valor digitado no console e coloca em nome 

    //cout equivale a printf() em C++
    std::cout << nome;

    //Outro forma de usar cout
    std::cout << "Nome: " << nome << " Idade: " << 10 << "\n";
    return 0;
}
```