# Diferença entre "<iostream>" ou "<stdlib.h> <stdio.h>" no #include

Tags: c++

Estou aprendendo a programar em c++, e gostaria de saber qual a diferença de em programar com a biblioteca

```
#include <iostream>
```

ou as bibliotecas

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
```

Uma eu usaria coisas como `std::cout e std::cin` e outra eu usaria `printf e scanf`.

Preciso saber programar com as duas ou posso seguir em uma somente, que no caso eu tava aprendendo com o  `std::cout`? Elas tem diferença em performace ou algo assim?

Comment: Duplicadas e/ou relacionadas [diferença-de-cout-para-printf-em-c](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/204071/diferen%C3%A7a-de-cout-para-printf-em-c), [posso-substituir-o-cout-e-printf](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/263407/posso-substituir-o-cout-e-printf/263411#263411), [cin-vs-scanf-qual-é-mais-rápido](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/126240/cin-vs-scanf-qual-%C3%A9-mais-r%C3%A1pido)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Uma é o I/O da biblioteca padrão C, outra é o I/O da Standard Template Library (STL) para C++. Não deve haver diferença substancial de performance entre elas.

Como profissional da área é bom conhecer as duas, porque V. encontrará ambas em código de terceiros.

Em C++ você tem a escolha de uma *OU* outra, sugiro não misturar porque o I/O é bufferizado (armazenado temporariamente em memória), aí a gravação em arquivo ou exibição no console (stdout/cout) pode acontecer numa ordem diferente da qual você esperava.

Pessoalmente prefiro a biblioteca C por conta das máscaras do printf() que conheço melhor e são empregadas em muitas linguagens diferentes de C, mas não entenda isto como uma recomendação. Use uma e outra e veja qual agrada mais. Muita gente diria que se você programa em C++ deveria evitar a biblioteca C padrão, preferindo o STL.

Comment: Obrigado pela resposta, vou pegar um conhecimento pra entender a biblioteca padrão de C e irei continuar a usar a (STL), pois aprendi inicialmente ela e me sinto mais confortavel com ela.

Comment: Eu gosto muito desta resposta. Tentou evitar a guerra de opiniões entre estilo 'c' e estilo 'c++'. Os dois estilos têm pontos bons e ruins.

Comment: @KyleA valeu :)